# Laravel 5.3 Authentication Issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am having issues grabbing the currently authenticated user in Laravel 5.3. More specifically, I am making a HTTP request to my api.php file, which has the route defined as api/test/create.

The controller code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Test;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'test_name' => 'required',
            'youtube_id' => 'required',
            'is_live_test' => 'required',
        ]);

        //Laravel 5.3 allows to get the user via request
        $user = $request->user;

        if($user) {
            return 'We are logged in';
        } else {
            return 'We are not logged in';
        }

        return '';      
    }
}
```

Every time it returns 'We are not logged in'. To test this out, I referenced {{ Auth::check() }} in my blade file, and that returns as '1'. I am not quite sure why the Controller does not recognize the user is logged in; any ideas?

I have tried different variations of referencing the authentication, including importing the Facade and doing Auth::check(), Auth::user(), but it brings the same result regardless.

Comment: its `$request->user()` and you need to make sure the route uses the `auth` middleware

Comment: Should the API routes have the auth middleware applied to them, though? Or does my call not belong in the API in that case?

Comment: the `api` middleware should have `auth:api`

Comment: and when using the `api` routes, you need to setup passport: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport

Comment: More specifically, for your users to consume the api: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Comment: I followed the steps outlined, and it still shows up as un-authenticated...

Comment: You will not be able to access the api route by going to the url directly

Comment: I am making the request via VueJS HTTP. Is it no longer supposed to go to /api/test/create ?

Comment: Yes it is, your JS should look something like this: `this.$http.get('/api/test/create')` - make sure you have the dev console open and view the network tab for any response

Comment: Hmm, that is exactly what I am doing, and I am getting the error
: "Unauthenticated"

Comment: Does your view have the CSRF token at the top of it still?

Comment: I was missing the CSRF token config for vue. It works now, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

Get user object with:

```
$user = $request->user();
```

Or:

```
$user = auth()->user();
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up -- still getting the 'not logged in', though.

Comment: Please show routes file contents. Also what routes file do you use?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
Auth::user();
```

also

```
auth()->user();
```

also

```
$request->user();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Auth::check()** method directly in the Controller.

```
if (Auth::check()){
    // User is logged in
    // Do something with the Authenticated User.
}else
{
    // User is not logged in
}
```

to get User Data do something like this

```
$user = Auth::user();

$userId = $user->id;
```

etc.